Finding the VIF of Standardized Variables in python
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import statsmodels.api as sm 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 
import seaborn as sns 
sns.set() 
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 

object= StandardScaler() 
standard = object.fit_transform(data_preprocessed) 
vif_columns = data_preprocessed.columns 

 for v in range(len(standard[0])): 
   data_ = standard[:,v] 
   data_i = pd.DataFrame(data_) 
   res = [variance_inflation_factor(data_i.values, i) for i in range(len(data_i.columns))] #Error Here 
   print(vif_columns[v]+" : "+res) 

#ERROR : zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

The Data is stored in a variable called data_preprocessed, I tried standardizing the data first before calculating the vif, after standardizing the data I got a two dimensional array with each row representing a row from the previous data_preprocessed, however when I try calculating the vif I keep getting an error : Zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity, can someone help me in explaining a workaround for the error and suggest any better solution to the problem
